# Easiest way to draw a scalar and vector field with C++?

Tags: c++, opengl, vector-graphics, scalar

What is the easiest, while being decently fast, way to draw a grid (say, 100 x 100) of scalar values as colors and vectors as lines from arrays of values in C++? Pure OpenGL? Something like this:

[image]

I am planning on using either basic OpenGL or SDL. This Windows program will be a real-time demonstration (not static image) and should be able to handle user (cursor) input. I do not think OpenGL alone can handle input.

Comment: Dont use c++ ... Is there a reason you need to? If its going to be quick and dirty use `python` with matplotlib, or matlab, or scilab?

Comment: @Ben I am doing some computationally intensive fluid modelling...though maybe numpy will work, I really do not think python is fast enough

Comment: OpenGL is quite inefficient when drawing lines. Just use GDI+.

Comment: C++ has no concept of graphics, drawing, etc. Yes there are libraries to do all those things, but you need to ask about those libraries, not just "c++". You haven't even said what platform you're on, what you want the output to do (is it a window? is it an image file?).

Comment: +1 on Python. Python is slow for numerical computation, but it's plenty fast for drawing a static image on screen. You also get ease of use and platform independence.

Comment: @Adam I have added some details

Comment: Do you're not asking how to draw an image, you're asking how to make a full-on GUI. I'll add "use javascript" to my answer. Alternatively you can use GLUT. If you read anything about creating a Windows GUI you'll quickly see why you're being steered away from C++.

Comment: @Adam I am clearly not trying to make a GUI, just get cursor position and click.

Comment: You're drawing a **G**raphic and having the **U**ser **I**nteract with it using the mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SDL_FillRect](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_FillRect) and [SDL_RenderDrawLine](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderDrawLine) are fast enough for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

In OpenGL you can create the array of floats wich can be represents as bitmap image

```
float computations[10000][3] = {
  { 1, 0.5, 0.5 }, // ..... 100 elements in row
  //..............................
  // 100 rows
};
```

Than call OpenGL function

```
glDrawPixels(100 /*width*/, 100 /*height*/, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, computations);
```

or using `glTexImage()`

```
glTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 100 /*width*/, 100 /*height*/, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, computations);
```

But it is wery important to represent the the float data in the range of [0; 1].

for example this code draws 8x8 image

```
float pixels[64][3]= {
    { 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, .0f, 1.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, .0f, 1.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
    { 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, .0f, 1.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, .0f, 1.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
    { 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, .0f, 1.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, .0f, 1.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
    { 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, .0f, 1.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, .0f, 1.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
    { 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, .0f, 1.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, .0f, 1.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
    { 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, .0f, 1.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, .0f, 1.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
    { 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, .0f, 1.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, .0f, 1.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
    { 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, .0f, 1.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, .0f, 1.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f } };

void RenderScene(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glRasterPos2i(0, 0);
    glDrawPixels(8, 8, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, pixels);

    glFlush();
}
```

the result will be

[image]

The result picture can be simply scaled using `glPixelZoom` or magnificated as texture filtration result.

here is example of texture loading.

```
glGenTextures(1, &g_nTexture);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_nTexture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_TRUE);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 8, 8, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, pixels);

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

the result of filtering.

[image]

here you can see smooth color transition.

There are others ways to do that things with shaders.

Vectors may be drawn separately as single line with the cone on its end than positioned by affine transformations.

This all things will give acceptable level of performance for real time application and wide capabilities of human-machine interaction because OS will handle any OpenGL window as native with all OS events support.

Comment: Would this be the same as just drawing rectangles?

Comment: @qwr: Yes. You can draw the rectangles and it will looks the same as drawing image.

Comment: @qwr: The only difference is in implementation.

Comment: @qwr: So choose what is more suitable for you.

Comment: @qwr: I think the most performance will go for color computation. To increase performance you may use OpenCL or other GPGPU stuff.

Comment: @qwr: With linear texture filtration will be easy to implement interpolation between nearest pixels (rectangle colors).